# Not able to execute nohup command inside shell script when called via ssh

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, solaris

solaris server I am connecting to has password less login enabled

```
ssh -n server@ipaddress "cd location/tocode;.  ~/.profile; nohup ./xxx.sh"
```

inside xxx.sh 
I am passing 2 commands

```
chmod 755 nohup.out
mv nohup.out nohup_log_xxdate.log
```

But getting error

```
can't access nohup.out
```

Comment: At the moment you run `chmod` `nohup.out` is open from `nohup` command

Comment: Can you do something like `nohup ./xxx2.sh > nohup_log_xxdate.log 2>&1 &` ?